# I am currently trying to click multiple links that will cause files to download. However I am unable to click more than one file

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, python-requests

I am trying to create code that will click multiple links on a webpage that will inturn download files. However, I have written an XPath that contains all the links. When trying to click I get this error: "click() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Is there any way to click all links in the desired XPath with .click() function in selenium?

This is what I am trying with 10 files:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'sys_attachment.do') and @class='linked formlink']").click('href')
```

Is there a better way to download all of these with the XPath? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure you are passing `href` as part of `click()` method. Just try with `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'sys_attachment.do') and @class='linked formlink']").click()`.

Comment: if you want to find many elements then use `find_elemenets_...` with **s** in word `elements` and you get list with many elements. And then you have to use `for`-loop to use `click()` (without arguments) on every element separatelly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. @furas could up please provide an example of using for loop to click one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `find_elements_by` instead of `element` so you can loop over the list of elements, and click on each one, ex:

```
clickList = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'sys_attachment.do') and @class='linked formlink']")

for count, elem in enumerate(clickList):
  # I am refreshing the list in case the DOM is changed
  currentList = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'sys_attachment.do') and @class='linked formlink']")
  currentList[count].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find many elements then use `find_elemenets_...` with `s` in word `elements` and you get list with many elements. And then you have to use `for`-loop to use `click()` (without arguments) on every element separatelly.

```
all_items = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'sys_attachment.do') and @class='linked formlink']")

for item in all_items:
    item.click()
```

---

Problem is when `click` changes page because then items stop exist and you would have to go back, find again all items and click next element on list - but you have to remeber index of previously clicked item.